# Creating new objects in C++ function causes program to crash

Tags: c++, function, object

I have a program which allows the user to play Dominoes against 3 CPU players, with varying difficulty. Each CPU player can be either Beginner, Intermediate or Expert, and each difficulty has it's own class. If I initiate my 3 CPU players at the beginning of my 'Window' class (below), the program runs fine.

In Window.h

```
public:
Window(QWidget *parent = 0);

Intermediate *cpu1;
Beginner *cpu2;
Intermediate *cpu3;
```

In Window.cpp

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)   {

cpu1 = new Intermediate;
cpu2 = new Beginner;
cpu3 = new Intermediate;
}
```

However I want the user to be able to select the CPU difficulties at the beginning of the game, so I now have a function within 'Window' that creates the objects. As soon as I call this function the game freezes and I get an error message pop up saying telling me the program has ended unexpectedly.

```
void Window:: startGame(){

cpu1 = new Intermediate;
cpu2 = new Beginner;
cpu3 = new Intermediate;
}
```

If anyone would be able to explain to me what is going on and what I can do to get around this that would be great.

Intermediate.cpp (Beginner.cpp is almost identical)

```
#include "intermediate.h"

Intermediate::Intermediate()
{
tilePlaced = false;
skipGo  = false;

}
void Intermediate::findDoubles(int a[7][2]){

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){             // Creates new doubles list after each go.
    doublesList[i] = 0;
}


for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){         // Creates a list of doubles
    if ((a[i][0] == a[i][1]) &&  (a[i][0] != 7)){
        doublesList[a[i][0]] = 1;
    }
}

}
bool Intermediate::addDomino(){}    // Function that finds best domino to replace and returns bool

if(tilePlaced == false){
    pass++;
    text += "\nPassed turn";
    return false;
}
else{
    pass = 0;
    text += QString("\nPlaced [%1 : %2]").arg(a).arg(b);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Include your class definitions please.

Comment: Show the contructors of `Beginner` and `Intermediate`.

Comment: Is `Intermediate *cpu1;
    Beginner *cpu2;
    Intermediate *cpu3;` not a class definition/constructor? Or is that a stupid question?

Comment: It is hard to tell from your incomplete code snippets, but I sense one problem here. You allocate memory in the constructor, and point cpu1/2/3 to them, and then in the startGame() method, you reassign those pointers to new memory. Do you actually cleanup the old memory allocated anywhere?

Comment: @T.S It is not a *stupid* question per se, but you have to show us the definition of classes Intermediate and Beginner. I guess you declare those in the files Intermediate.h/cpp and Beginner.h/cpp. Show those.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Your question is probably platform specific.

Comment: Oh apologies, I'm still trying to work out what everything means. I will add both files.

Comment: @T.S No need to apologise, we are all beginners at some time. :-)

Comment: Side note: calling function `startGame()` will result with memory leaks.

Comment: Side note #2: Don't dump your entire source code in here. Debug it as much as needed, find out where the problem is taking place at, and then add that piece of code along with everything that you think is relevant. In addition, fix the indentation. You need to make a little more effort in formatting your question if you're expecting others to make an effort answering it.

Comment: Are the memory leaks caused by creating the new objects of the classes? Or by one of the numerous other errors in my code?!

Answer (score 1):

One way to start would be to narrow down which class is causing the fault.  Does it work if they are all Beginner, or if they are all Intermediate?  If so then the other one is causing the problem.

Comment: No I've tried all sorts of combinations, the only thing that causes the problem is creating the objects within a function as apposed to at the beginning of the class